# protect against sql injection when the sql is being transmitted via XML

Tags: sql-server, perl, sql-injection, aspdotnetstorefront

[This Raw SQL WSI API](http://manual.aspdotnetstorefront.com/p-1459-executesql.aspx) appears very powerful, but it also appears to be the only way to accomplish retrieving the id's of entities I need. I need to be able to, retrieve manufacturer by name for example (debating on whether there's a better way). On the assumption the best way is to send a query like this

```
'SELECT ManufactuerGUID FROM Manufacturer WHERE Name = ' . "$name"
```

which is a really bad idea and I hate myself for even writing that... but I'm not sure how best to sanitize it. usually the parameterization is done via the sql driver (AFAIK), the only thing I can think of... is could I perhaps get the final SQL string back from [DBD::ODBC](http://metacpan.org/module/DBD%3a%3aODBC)? Other suggestions welcome. Perhaps there is a sanitization library I could use?

To clarify, I have no actual control over ASP.net Storefront's API. the Manufacturer `Name` is the only parameter that comes from human input so I shouldn't have to worry about how I code the rest of it. Yes this API is an incredibly stupid idea, and it'd be great if they had given me a way to parameterize the query.

Comment: This Raw API appears to be very pointless actually. **Nobody** ever need sql transmitted via XML. There are regular ways used by everyone: you send only *which* query [already written in your code] to run, and what *data* to use. Please don't reinvent the wheel. Don't send SQL via XML.

Comment: @YourCommonSense... then tell me what I should send that will return the data I need (the guid), based on the parameter I have ( manufacturer name ). I'm not reinventing a wheel, I did not write this API. I'm simply interfacing with it.

Comment: yeah... whoever downvoted this when I found a better answer, thanks much. It's not like it was /easy/ to find the interface that does this.

Comment: It's still not an answer but nonsense. Why can't I simple rewrite the query in XML?

Comment: the only apis that do that either return far more data than I need or far less. Unfortunately they tend to require me to lookup by id or guid, which I don't have at the time of lookup. There is an XPath option in a different call, unfortunately I've found it returns insufficient data in some cases and too much in others, it's inconsistent in the amount of data it returns for differing entities. It is possible I could use Xpath to get the Guid, then do another query to get all the data, then do my updates. This results in more RPC calls than using the SQL interface though.

Comment: Ultimately it's entirely possible that I could... because I keep stumbling on API's like Get and GetEntity, and then this addition to the SQL which documents QueryParameters. It's possible I haven't found the documentation I need yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [this documentation](http://manual.aspdotnetstorefront.com/p-157-xml-packages.aspx) which suggests there is a QueryParams option.

```
<query name="Entities" rowElementName="Entity"> 
<sql> 
 <![CDATA[ 
  select Name,Description from {EntityName} with (NOLOCK) where {EntityName}ID=@EntityID 
]]> 
</sql> 
<querystringreplace replaceTag="{EntityName}" 
    replacetype="runtime" 
    replaceparamname="EntityName" 
    defvalue="" 
    validationpattern="(category)|(section)|(affiliate)|(manufacturer)|(distributor)|(library)" /> 
<queryparam paramname="@EntityID" 
    paramtype="runtime" 
    requestparamname="EntityID" 
    sqlDataType="int" 
    defvalue="0" 
    validationpattern="" /> 
</query>
```

I believe this is sufficient to prevent sql injection (though it'd be nice to have someone that knows the product confirm). Why this isn't mentioned at all in the main SQL interface documentation I'll never understand.

Answer (score 2):

`DBI` provides a `quote` method. It's probably best to use this method with a real connection to the targetted database, but if cannot do this, you can also use the `NullP` driver instead.

```
use DBI;
my $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:NullP:");
my $quoted_name = $dbh->quote($name);
```

Note that the result of `quote` already has single or double quotes around it, so you don't have to write them yourself.

Comment: although this is the correct solution to my question, and a great answer, I have stumbled across documentation that implies there is a way to parameterize the queries. Which is obviously better than manual quoting. (This is still the best way though if an API doesn't provide any parameterization options).

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you have a table called ManufactuerGUID and you could so easily code CRUDS to that.... Outside of that you are asking the best way to make a bad situation better...How about Using SqlParameters for your output and the parsing will still reject bad things.

Comment: I do not control the API